# How to secure mine as well as other people' passwords on the computer used by my receptionist?

Tags: account-security, protection, safe-browsing-filter

My friend runs an office in which the computer used by the receptionist is used by so many people including my friend and others (so many people come there for job recruitment) who frequently save their passwords on browsers.

Today I was talking to the receptionist as we know each other very well and while discussing hacking, I told him how to view saved passwords on chrome and then realised my mistake. What do you think is the best way to secure password saved even accidentally on that pc so that the receptionist won't ever be able to view any of em?

Currently I have suggested him lastpass (although its more of a password manager, on first installation it removes all the unsafe passwords and even if any others are saved then makes them inaccessible by a master password).

Comment: Dedicated users. And a master password for the browser.

Comment: Can you please provide me a good link for a tutorial? Thanks

Comment: Questions for links are off-topic here as they might render unusable in the future

Comment: How come its unusable if it is related to the tags in questions? Well I have again posted the comment under the answer. (I'm new to stack exchange and its android interface is a little bit confusing for first time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dedicated users. Remove the passwords that are saved and move to a computer use model that don't involve shared accounts. Don't give your receptionist (or anyone but Sys Admins) privileged access to systems. Ideally get all of your users using password storage such as KeePass, LastPass, etc.

Comment: If there's a PC used by applicants, have that be a separate PC in kiosk mode.  You don't know the people that are applying there and it only takes one bad guy to infect your network under the model asked in the question.

Comment: Can you please direct me to a good tutorial link? Thanks

Comment: As I mentioned before, questions for links are off topic here. This is because links might become unreachable in the future. Additionally, you do not specify the OS and we are not google.

Comment: @user163768 what would be best is if you searched google for something like "Kiosk Deployment" and came back with any implementation questions related to security.